# apply( )-like function retrieving information of several dataframes for substituting a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, ode

I have a problem that is as follows: I have two dataframes (`parameters`and `amounts`).

```
> head(parameters)
        Ka       V1        V2   Q        CL
1 5.960224 20.46632  90.48670 5.5 68.192196
2 1.176143 16.05779 132.44959 5.5  6.421357
3 1.324476 34.91569  42.96544 5.5 20.761933
4 2.649055 21.55833 111.89387 5.5  6.868612
5 1.495101 32.97900 140.82672 5.5  4.340567
6 2.807148 29.33883 206.71401 5.5  8.756406

>head(amounts)
  Depot Central Peripheral
1    10       0          0
2    10       0          0
3    10       0          0
4    10       0          0
5    10       0          0
6    10       0          0
```

I would like to pass each row of `parameters` & `amounts` to a ODE-solver named `ode`, part of the `deSolve`package. I came with the following answer using a `for`loop, it works fine, but it takes ages when the number of loops is high (i.e, more than 500 iterations). I would like to substitute the `for`loop with an `apply`-like function. This is the loop:

```
Central_concs <- vector()

for(i in 1:nrow(parameters)){
  n_a <- names(amounts)
  amounts_i <- as.numeric(amounts[i, ])
  names(amounts_i) <- n_a
  parameters_i <- parameters[i, ]
  out <- ode(y = amounts_i, times = times, func = TwoComp, parms = parameters_i)
  Central_concs <- cbind(Central_concs, out)
}
```

The name extraction and re-naming is just an issue with the `ode`function, don't worry about it. `TwoComp`, argument passed to `ode`, is just a function containing the system of differential equations.

I have tried with apply, but I have been totally unsuccessful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 2 general tips: Only put terms in your for loop which depend on i. For example `na<-names(amount)` you can put in front of the for loop. Then it is calculated just once.

Comment: The other tip: `dataframe` is slower than `matrix` especially when extracting rows as you do. Since all values are numeric you could work with matrices instead.

Comment: The use of apply is in general a good idea, but the for-loop is probably not the reason that the simulation "takes ages". I don't expect that apply makes it faster. The good news is, that there are several ways to make deSolve models faster: appropriate use of solvers, consequent vectorization of the model, use of compiled code. You may consider to ask a question about this.

Comment: Yes, I realized that the use of apply reduces the computing time from 50-55s down to 35, thus being a long time for use in Shiny apps, which is the intention. So yes, it's an improvement, but I will also consider going deeper into deSolve. Thanks!

Comment: One question regarding your last post: does your model use events or have you switched to a forcing function? I ask because a forcing function approach may be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
parameters_matrix <- as.matrix(parameters)
amoumts_matrix <- as.matrix(amounts)

myfun <- function(i){
  ode(y = amounts_matrix[i, ], times = times, func = TwoComp, parms = parameters_matrix[i,])
}


sapply(X =  1:nrow(parameters), FUN = myfun)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
custom.ode <- function(i){
  n_a <- names(amounts)
  amounts_i <- as.numeric(amounts[i, ])
  names(amounts_i) <- n_a
  parameters_i <- parameters[i, ]
  out <- ode(y = amounts_i, times = times, func = TwoComp, parms = parameters_i)
  return(out)
}


Central_concs <- lapply(1:nrow(amounts), custom.ode)
```